# Como usar o metódo slice com valores negativos?

Tags: javascript

Por exemplo, tenho o seguinte código:

```
    var name = "maria mendonça maria maria dos santos";
    window.alert(name.slice(-6, 0));
```

E quero retornar santos com números negativos. Como capturar a posição de "s"? Não era para ser 0 ou -0?

Comment: De qual "s" em **s**anto**s** você está falando?

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, para retornar o primeiro "s" de "santos", você teria que definir o segundo argumento com `-5`:

```js
var name = "maria mendonça maria maria dos santos";
console.log(name.slice(-6, -5));
```

E para retornar "santos", bastaria omitir o segundo argumento:

```js
var name = "maria mendonça maria maria dos santos";
console.log(name.slice(-6));
```

Porque aí ele vai pegar à partir do 6º caratere até o final da string, de trás pra frente. O valor `0` não é aplicável no segundo argumento.

Se quiser pegar o segundo "s"  de "santos", usaria `-1`:

```js
var name = "maria mendonça maria maria dos santos";
console.log(name.slice(-1));
```

Quando você quiser usar valor negativo, não irá usar os índices da string, apenas a posição de trás pra frente começando do número 1 pra cima, negativos:

```
var name = "maria mendonça maria maria dos santos";

// de trás pra frente:

s = -1
o = -2
t = -3
n = -4
a = -5
s = -6
...
```

Comment: Há valeu amigão ajudou bastante num sabia hehe mais valeu mesmo!